# Unknown rotation behaviour of gameObject while trying to rotate using LocalEulerAngles

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am new to game development , I am following a book Unity in action by Manning . This is the code snippet used to rotate a game object (from the book):

```
public RotationAxes axes = RotationAxes.MouseXandY;
public float sensitivityHorizontal = 9.0f;
public float sensitivityVert = 9.0f;

private float rotationX = 0;
public float minimumVert = -45.0f;
public float maximumVert = 45.0f;

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    float input = Input.GetAxis ("Mouse X");

        //Vertical Rotation
    if (axes == RotationAxes.MouseY) {
        rotationX-= Input.GetAxis ("Mouse Y") * sensitivityVert;
        rotationX = Mathf.Clamp (rotationX, minimumVert, maximumVert);
        float rotationY = transform.localEulerAngles.y;

        transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3 (rotationX, rotationY, 0);

    }

}
```

This code actually works but the other way around i.e when my move my mouse upwards the object rotates down and up when I move down . I figured out that it was `rotationX-= Input.GetAxis ("Mouse Y") * sensitivityVert;` this that was causing the problem so I change it to `rotationX+= Input.GetAxis ("Mouse Y") * sensitivityVert;` and now it rotates really strangely ! I have made sure that it only rotates in vertical axis but **it's rotating in all the directions i.e even in horizontal and z axis**.
Can somebody please tell me where I am going wrong? ThankYou

Comment: have you tried rotation using sharpgl?

Comment: no I want to do it this way

Comment: Are you working from a `Vector.Zero` rotation? or do you have some default rotation on the object you are trying to rotate.

Comment: if (axes == RotationAxes.MouseY) returns false. please simplify your code

Answer (score 1):

Works fine for me. I cleaned up your code and constrained Y to its initial value.

```
public class rotateX : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float sensitivityVert = 9.0f;

    private float rotationX = 0;
    public float minimumVert = -45.0f;
    public float maximumVert = 45.0f;

    Vector3 initial;

    void Start()
    {
        initial = transform.localEulerAngles;
    }

    // OnMouseDown is called when the user has pressed the 
    // mouse button while over the GUIElement or Collider.
    protected void OnMouseDown()
    {
        sign = -sign;
    }
    float sign = -1f;

    void Update()
    {
        rotationX += sign * Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * sensitivityVert;
        //rotationX = Mathf.Clamp(rotationX, minimumVert, maximumVert);

        transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(rotationX, initial.y, 0f);
    }
}
```

The cube rotates up and down around its pivot.

Comment: Works For me too! but because of  `rotationX -= Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * sensitivityVert;`     when I move my mouse up the gameObject looks down and when I move mouse down object looks up!! what to do?

Comment: I don't have unity open at the moment, but you could use `-rotationX` in the `Vector3` assignment, like this `transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(-rotationX, initial.y, 0f);` That should flip the sign.

Comment: Yep I tried all that long before I posted this question! when i do that the rotation acts very strangely

Comment: Ok, don't do that. Leave the code as is, or comment out the clamp as I just did, to see that it works fine. Walk to the other side of the cube to see that it rotates up when you look up, and down when you look down. Or if you can't move, change the `-=` to `+=`, but that will have the same affect if you can move and you are on the wrong side of the cube.

Comment: @MR.JOIS Added a click handler to the rotate script. Now you can click the cube to change the rotation direction. Be sure your cube (object) has a collider active on it.